# Copying text from one google Doc, to another active google Doc

Tags: javascript, google-docs, google-docs-api

I have a body of text in a master document(google Doc) that is located in an Admin Folder, that I would like to copy to the active google Doc that I am working on (that will be blank, if that helps).

I am quite new at JS, and have been trying to use the `getFileById(fileId).makeCopy`, but am struggling.

Any pointers as to what tutorials I should look at or how I could go about doing this would be of great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open script.google.com from the document:

> Tools -> Script Editor

Use this function:

```
function textCopy() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById('ID_OF_DOC_TO_BE_COPIED').getText();
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  var text = body.editAsText();
  // Insert text at the beginning of the document.
  text.insertText(0, doc);
}
```

Run it. Some permissions will be asked, be sure to allow it.

More info about doc text manipulation can be found in [Class Text](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#getText()).

Comment: It worked perfectly. Thank you so much!
I appreciate the extra link to that documentation as well.

Cheers!

Comment: Is there a way to copy and paste with formatting?